# Laravel 4 htaccess vhost NotFoundHttpException issue on wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp, laravel

I have installed a local copy of Laravel 4 on WAMP, windows 7 64-bit, running apache2.4 and php5.4. I have set up a virtualhost for this project, as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/Google Drive/project/public"
ServerName project
<directory "c:/Google Drive/project/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works correctly when I try to access `project/`. When I try to access the default Home controller from `project/index.php?home`, it works correctly as well. However, when I try to access the default Home controller from `project/home/`, I get a `NotFoundHttpException` thrown by Laravel 4.

I'm using the default `.htaccess` file as provided by Laravel 4:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What's the proper way of removing index.php from the URL without Laravel 4 throwing `NotFoundHttpException`?

Comment: is mod_rewrite ON on your apache server?

Comment: Also, better remove that whitespace in your path between `Google` and `Drive`. Could potentially cause some problems... btw have you tried the alternate .htaccess? http://four.laravel.com/docs/installation on the bottom

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled on the server. I've tried a different location (c:/project/public), does the same thing. Also no luck with the alternate .htaccess. Still the NotFoundHttpException thrown by Laravel 4.

Comment: Please can you post the content of the `Route` function that directs to your Home controller?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, from the [Laravel Docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/installation) (see installation -> Pretty URLs)?

"If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This seems to work for me.  I am also using WAMP (XAMPP, actually) on Win7 64 bit, etc.   but I do not use a virtual host.